# Xamarin - Google Cloud Messaging - error: package com.google.android.gms.iid does not exist

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to get Google Cloud Messaging working according to [Xamarin's example.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/)

All has been going good until I tried to deploy the app with this piece of code:

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" })]
    class MyInstanceIDListenerService : InstanceIDListenerService
    {
        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var intent = new Intent (this, typeof (RegistrationIntentService));
            StartService (intent);
        }
    }
```

Then I get an error that reads:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       error: package com.google.android.gms.iid does not exist
    extends com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService
```

and:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       error: cannot find symbol
        if (getClass () == MyInstanceIDListenerService.class)
  symbol:   method getClass()
  location: class MyInstanceIDListenerService
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I checked my SDK folders to make sure all packages were properly extracted and they are:

[image]

Does this look like a Xamarin bug or is there something wrong on my side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually one of the sdk zip files was corrupted and I had to download it manually and extract it. After hitting "clean and build" the build worked fine.