# Xamarin error: package android.support.* doesn't exist

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-support-library

I'm just starting to explore field of mobile app developement (using VS2015 community with Xamarin) and I've already encountered following problem.

I'm trying to follow an example for creating a simple RecycleView App as it's described in this [article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/). But when I try to build it, I get 81 errors of quite similar content:

```
 error: package android.support.* does not exist
```

(See [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAMp0.png))

I've searched for similar problem descriptions on SO and found these topics:

- [Error after installing Android v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915969/error-even-after-installing-android-v4-support-library-in-xamarin/32212195#32212195)
- [Build error missing files inside AppData local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418129/xamarin-forms-android-project-build-error-missing-files-inside-appdata-local)
- [Error package com google Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154755/xamarin-google-cloud-messaging-error-package-com-google-android-gms-iid-doe)

I've tried every solution presented there, but nothing worked so far.

I've also reloaded android.support libraries via NuGet into my project file several times using both Console and Package Manager. Moreover, I've tried to start the project from scratch, but no luck as well.

Any idea what this error may be related to?

If there's a need for any additional info, I'll be glad to present it to you.

And I'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/05/android-support-repository-and-xamarin-android/